# Create a month for every date between a period and make them columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to separate every month inside the period between the 'start' and 'end' column than I know I can use a pivot_table to make them columns:

```
subscription|values| start   | end
x           |1     |5/5/2018 |6/5/2018
y           |2     |5/5/2018 |8/5/2018
z           |1     |5/5/2018 |9/5/2018
a           |3     |5/5/2018 |10/5/2018
b           |4     |5/5/2018 |11/5/2018
c           |2     |5/5/2018 |12/5/2018
```

Desired Output:

```
subscription|jan| feb | mar | abr | jun | jul | aug | sep | out | nov | dez
x           |   |     |     |     | 1   | 1   |     |     |     |     |
y           |   |     |     |     | 2   | 2   | 2   |     |     |     |
z           |   |     |     |     | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |     |     |
a           |   |     |     |     | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   |     |
b           |   |     |     |     | 4   | 4   | 4   | 4   | 4   | 4   |
c           |   |     |     |     | 2   | 2   | 2   | 2   | 2   | 2   | 2
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: made the difference between the end and start
df['dif']=df['end']-df['start']
also tried to generate the pivor_table even without the months
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='values', index='subscription', columns='dif')

Comment: Not really useful ;-) A naive approach would be to create a new column for every month, and then set the value of this column depending on whether this month is comprised between "end" and "start". Here are some pointers: ``DataFrame.assign`` to create columns, ``Series.where`` to set values based on a condition, ``Series.between`` to check that a value is between two other values, ``pandas.Timestamp`` to create dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
import calendar
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=[len(df),13]), 
                   columns=map(lambda s: calendar.month_abbr[s], 
                                        np.arange(13)))
```

First set begin as values, and end as `-values`.

```
r = np.arange(len(df))
df2.values[r, df.start.dt.month] =  df['values']
df2.values[r, df.end.dt.month]   = -df['values']
```

Then `cumsum` through `axis=1`
    df2 = df2.cumsum(1)

Set the final to `values`

```
df2.values[r, df.end.dt.month]= df['values']
```

Final output:

```
        Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   3   3   3   3   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

Comment: this is very good thank you. I just forgot to mention that in my real database the period in many times have 1 year or more. thus, in those cases, the values are colliding and becoming negative. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @RicardoFernandes Whats the output in that case?

Answer (score 0):

A method from `sklearn` `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
df['L'] = [pd.date_range(x, y, freq='M') for x, y in zip(df.start, df.end)]
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
yourdf=pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['L']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index).mul(df['values'],0)
yourdf.columns=yourdf.columns.strftime('%Y%B')
yourdf['subscription']=df['subscription']
yourdf
Out[75]: 
   2018May  2018June      ...       2018November  subscription
0        1         0      ...                  0             x
1        2         2      ...                  0             y
2        1         1      ...                  0             z
3        3         3      ...                  0             a
4        4         4      ...                  0             b
5        2         2      ...                  2             c
[6 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: what is df['L]?